# access vba change visibility of a variable control in a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, controls, visibility, subforms

I'm trying to create a sub that will toggle the visibility of a given array  of controls in a given form location. I've managed to make it work on a main form, but can't figure out the syntax for a subform control. I'm working with Access 2016.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub toggleDisappear(ByRef fields() As Variant, _
    ByVal report As String, ByVal vis As Boolean, Optional ByVal sfrm As String)

If IsNull(sfrm) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(fields)
        Forms(report).Controls(fields(i)).Visible = vis
    Next
Else
    For i = 1 To UBound(fields)
        Forms.Form(report).Controls(sfrm).Form.Controls(fields(i)).Visible = vis
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? I get a run-time error 438 - "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: http://access.mvps.org/Access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: What line triggers that error? String variables cannot hold Null, only Variant type can. So either declare the variable as Variant or test for empty string: `If sfrm = "" Then`.

Comment: I thought that was it, but it wasn't. The line that starts "Forms.Form(Report)..." triggers the error. I set the sfrm variable to variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `sFrm` as `String` in VBA, it can never be null. Therefore your If statement will not work properly. To fix:

Change your procedure declaration to:

```
Sub toggleDisappear(ByRef fields() As Variant, _
    ByVal report As String, ByVal vis As Boolean, Optional ByVal sfrm As Variant)
```

Then, change your If statement to:

```
If IsMissing(sfrm) Then
```

Now your code can tell when `sFrm` is not supplied.